# Django, url does not match

Tags: python, django

This may be a duplicate question but I can't find any answer here on SO.
I'm trying to write a method able to take two different models. I have a Post model and a Comment model, and I want the vote_up method to handle voting for both of these.

views.py

```
def vote_up(request, obj): #portotype not working atm...
    if isinstance(obj, Post):
        o = Post.objects.get(id=obj.id)
    elif isinstance(obj, Comment):
        o = Comment.objects.get(id=obj.id)
    else:           
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) #add 'something went wrong' message
    o.votes += 1    
    o.save()    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^vote_up/(?P<obj>\d+)/$', 'post.views.vote_up'),
    url(r'^post_vote_down/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'post.views.post_vote_down'), # works fine no instance check here, using separate methods for Post/Comment
    url(r'^comment_vote_down/(?P<comment_id>\d+)/$', 'post.views.comment_vote_down'),
)
```

The errors i get is listing my existing urls and:
The current URL, post/vote_up/Post object, didn't match any of these.
or
The current URL, post/vote_up/Comment object, didn't match any of these.

I'm guessing \d+ is the villain but can't seem to find the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Burhan says, you can't send an object in a URL, only a key. But another approach would be to include the model in the URLconf itself: you can use a single pattern, but capture the model name there as well.

```
url(r'^(?P<model>post|comment)_vote_down/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'post.views.post_vote_down'),
```

)

then in the view:

```
def vote_up(request, model, pk):
    model_dict = {'post': Post, 'comment': Comment}
    model_class = model_dict[model]
    o = model_class.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 url(r'^vote_up/(?P<obj>\d+)/$', 'post.views.vote_up'),
```

To

```
url(r'^vote_up/(?P<obj>[-\w]+)/$', 'post.views.vote_up'),
```

`\d+` means only integer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an object in the URL, you need to send the primary key and then retrieve the corresponding object from the database.

```
def vote_up(request, obj): #portotype not working atm...
    try:
        o = Post.objects.get(pk=obj)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        o = Comment.objects.get(pk=obj)
        except Comment.DoesNotExist:           
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    o.votes += 1    
    o.save()    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between comment and post in your url:

urls.py

```
url(r'^vote_up/(?P<object_name>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'post.views.vote_up'),
```

views.py

```
def vote_up(request, object_name, id):
    if object_name == 'comment':
        # get id for comment
    if object_name == 'post':
        # get id for post
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```